# iOS IMAP Synchronization With MailCore Best Practices

Tags: ios, email, ios6, imap, mailcore

I'm developing an application where a local Core Data database is kept in sync with the user's IMAP email account. I'm using MailCore (http://libmailcore.com) to handle all the IMAP API calls, but there seems to be some shortcomings. Here is what I want my app to be able to do:

- Have a local copy of the most recent 50 emails on the server
- Download all new emails the user has received since the last fetch, keeping a maximum of 50 still on the device.
- Delete local emails that have been deleted on the server.

The only methods MailCore supplies for retrieving email are the following:

```
- (NSArray *)messagesFromSequenceNumber:(NSUInteger)startNum to:(NSUInteger)endNum withFetchAttributes:(CTFetchAttributes)attrs

- (NSArray *)messagesFromUID:(NSUInteger)startUID to:(NSUInteger)endUID withFetchAttributes:(CTFetchAttributes)attrs
```

Right now, I'm retrieving the latest emails from the server and downloading all the information about them, and then I retrieve the latest 50 UIDs from the server and compare them against my local cache to see what has been deleted. This seems very inefficient. Is there a better way to sync inboxes without two round trips to the server (at minimum)?

Comment: We are also working with mailcore and due to its poor documentation we couldn't find out even simple tasks like getting all headers of the email. May you help us

Answer (score 0):

check for imap servers  capabilities. Implementation of NOOP and imap idle capability is the answers to your query.